# How to use contain to filter multiple values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join, contains

I have two table item table and transaction table. I need to use Contain to filter for two values.

```
var list1= table.select(c=> new {c.ID , c.ItemID}).tolist();

var list2 = tableItem.where(x=> list1.contains(x.id ,x.itemID ));
```

Comment: is there any issue your are facing ?

Comment: Should the second line be like `var list2 = tableITem.where(x=> list1.contains(x.id ,x.itemID ));`?

Comment: There are many problems with that code that would have to be fixed before this question could be answered (assuming a question has actually been asked, which is debatable)...please post something that compiles, and perhaps define the classes to a small degree.

Comment: `var result = secondList.Where(second => firstList.Any(first => first.Id == second.Id && first.itemId == second.itemId));`

Answer (score 1):

This *should* work for you, may require a few tweaks since you're syntax looks a little rough.
Note the `Any` LINQ function I used.  More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var list1 = table.Select(c => new { c.ID, c.ItemID }).ToList();

var list2 = tableITem.Where(x => list1.Any(a => a.ID == x.id && a.ItemID == x.itemID)).ToList();
```

Comment: hello airn ,  thanks for  help me , but cant  access x.id ... why ..?

Comment: First, if this answered your question, please accept it as the answer and upvote if you didn't already.  Without seeing more of your classes, I can't say what `x.id` is supposed to be.  You didn't provide much code context, so I didn't have much to go off of.  More complete questions = more complete answers